# Route two different URL to the same ec2 instance with two php applications

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, virtualhost

I have two url domain, abc.com and xyz.com. Both domain were setted to go to same ec2 instance at Amazon. I have two php application on this server, one deployed at /var/www/html and  the other one at /var/www/html/xyz.

My issue is how change the httpd.conf config file to redirect all user that access by abc.com to the root site and all traffic by xyz.com go to /var/www/html/xyz

I tried do it adding the following code.

```
<VirtualHost xyz.com.br:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.com.br
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
    Alias /wedding "/var/www/html/xyz"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost abc.com.br:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName abc.com.br
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some trial and error, I finally got it.

First I put each site inside a subfolder of /var/www/html.
/var/www/html/abc
/var/www/html/xyz

At my httpd.conf I add the following code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias www.xyz.com
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
    ServerName abc.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.com
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

For each wordpress settings I changed the wordpress url and site url to the respective domain url and "Voilà", it's working!